# Microsoft Outlook .pst file equivalent for the Thunderbird Mail Client?

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird is installed MacOS: 5+ email accounts.

The goal is to export one of the G-mail account's for a third party to analyze in a Windows instance of Thunderbird. Once the emails are exported to a single data file, I would like to reduce the emails so as to ensure that analyst time is not wasted.

**Is there an equivalent of a Microsoft Outlook .pst file for the Thunderbird Mail Client and where is it found?**

I understand that the profile data is stored in:

```
open ~/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles
```

but unsure if the G-mail messages are contained in the profiles directory.

I seek to **avoid copying and sharing the G-mail login credential** and would like to avoid exporting this information.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird stores messages and other user data in a set of file called a "profile" often hidden.

To find your profile, first select the email account in TB (if you have multiple accounts).

```
Click on the menu button or menu bar in TB.
From the Help menu, click Troubleshooting Information.
In the Application Basics section, Profile Directory, click on Open Directory.
The Files window will show the name of the profile as well as the path to it.
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[reference](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-thunderbird-stores-user-data#w_where-is-my-profile-stored)

Comment: Will the procedure transfer the login credentials?  I seek to avoid transferring login credentials

Comment: As with any procedure such as this, changing passwords before hand and then after to something different will help preserve security.